Can you help me identify this orange/yellow stuff in my crawlspace?
I've noticed this orangeish/yellowish stuff in my crawlspace. I've had a plumber and a restoration expert look at it and they both said it looks like deteriorated insulation, but it's underneath the vapor barrier in some places.
It doesn't seem to grow and I've been inspecting the joists and center beam for signs of mold. Humidity sits around 55%, so I feel fairly confident it's not mold.



Efflorescence, I think. Minerals carried by a tiny amount of water.  Mostly harmless if so.

I agree with keshlam.  It is a product of nature. The color the result of whatever organics have combined chemically. Normally orange is the result when iron is present. Nothing to worry about any more than the gray stuff or the black stuff.  None of it if dangerous unless you eat it or rub it into a wound.

You can see if it's attracted to a rare earth magnet. If so, it's an iron-containing material either naturally occurring or resulting from rusting of construction materials. If not, it could still be iron but not one of the magnetic compounds.

Sure it's not rust?
